# Correlate vectors in different cells Pyspark - DataFrame or RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I've run into this problem using Pyspark on Spark 2.0 and I can't seem to figure out if I need to reshape the data further or if I can correlate the vectors in each cell in a DataFrame/RowRDD.

I have a RowRDD that I'm working with that looks like this:

```
[Row(aa_product=1, apr=[45, 58, 25, 3, 54, 28], may=[91, 5, 15, 93, 78, 98]),
 Row(aa_product=2, apr=[64, 69, 93, 75, 59, 2], may=[27, 6, 15, 11, 33, 2]),
 Row(aa_product=3, apr=[27, 22, 95, 56, 76, 33], may=[70, 88, 24, 49, 33, 70]),
 Row(aa_product=4, apr=[58, 10, 93, 93, 26, 56], may=[89, 47, 8, 94, 84, 89]),
 Row(aa_product=5, apr=[15, 99, 55, 79, 33, 17], may=[70, 65, 13, 77, 92, 89])]
```

There are additional columns for each month of the year, and they all contain a list of integers like you see here.

In DataFrame form:

```
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|aa_product|                 apr|                 may|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|         1|[89, 53, 12, 61, ...|[58, 66, 27, 43, ...|
|         2|[73, 83, 61, 90, ...|[37, 89, 69, 11, ...|
|         3|[91, 13, 94, 69, ...|[48, 76, 54, 13, ...|
|         4|[66, 28, 7, 100, ...|[58, 57, 11, 14, ...|
|         5|[21, 58, 70, 52, ...|[87, 85, 43, 41, ...|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

What I would like to do is correlate each product with each other product in each month.  So for instance, correlate the vector in `apr` for `aa_product = 1` with the vectors for products 2:5 in April *as well as* the correlation between the April and May vectors for each product.

I figured out how to explode each list into it's own unique product_month column, which would ultimately provide me the solution I need, but the scale of this project makes that solution prohibitive.  Is it possible to access these vectors in a programmatic way and correlate them to eachother?  An RDD or DataFrame solution is fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i solved similar problem related to correlation of columns using **mappartitions** in spark-scala. inside mappartitions write your custom code how you want to calculate correlation for each partitions. Hope you understand :)